1С Не видно макеты печатных форм
Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть причиной "невидимости" макетов печатных форм по пути "НСИ и Администрирование - Администрирование - Печатные формы, отчеты и обработки - Макеты печатных форм"?


Какие макеты не видно? Уточните вопрос.
